# Recommended tool to convert PostgreSQL database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a postgresql dump file and wants to convert it to MySQL. I google it and found pg2mysql which it converted successfully. However, I get errors when importing it to mysql. Looks like the formats are not compatible or wrong.

Any one can recommend?

Thanks.
James

Comment: Post the errors so we can better assist you. For the record, why are you converting?

Comment: This question is probably more suited to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) than SO.

Comment: @MikePurcell - This is the errors http://pastebin.ca/2141111

Comment: This is probably better asked on dba.stackexchange.com, but you'll need to provide a lot more information (what errors, etc). If you can edit your question to include that, I can migrate this for you with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for a migration would be a conversion tool like ESF data migration toolkit or openDBcopy that is open source.

Answer (score 0):

According to your [pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/2141111), the problem is with `bigserial`, as this is not a MySQL datatype. Some Googling came across this [site](http://www.ispirer.com/wiki/sqlways/postgresql/data-types/bigserial) which describes what bigserial is in Postgres context and other RDBMS datatype equivalents.

Looks like there are 3rd party libraries which will convert the data from Postgres to whichever RDMBS you choose, an example is [easyfrom.net](http://www.easyfrom.net/), if this doesn't fit your needs, just google around, as you are not the first person to need this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This ESF Database Migration Toolkit is working but the cost is quite expensive. This is really challenging for me because I have no skills any in database.

Comment: Cost as in $$, or cost as in performance?